# Is it possible to simulate a button click with a script/function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that only shows when I press a button, but I also have a menu with anchor link to that div, but it only works when the div is not hidden. Since the div only shows when I press the button, is there any way to "press" or simulate the button click with a function?

```html
<ul class="navList">
      <li><a href="#tools"><b>Tools</b></a>
        <div>
          <a href="#1">Calculate SubGhz channel</a>
        </div>
      </li>  
</ul>

<button class="collapsible">Calculate SubGhz channel</button>
   <div class="content">
    <br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="labels">Page:</td>
            <td><input class="labels" type="number" id="channel" value="28"></td>
            <td></td>
            <th class="label"rowspan="2">Output:</th>
            <th class="result"rowspan="2"><output id="resultSubGHZ"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="labels">Channel:</td>
            <td><input class="labels" type="number" id="page" Value="0"></td>
            <td><input type="button" onclick="CalculateSubGhzPage()" value="Calculate"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
   </div>
```

Comment: `button.click()`

Comment: Hi! If you could post a bit of your code we can give you a specific example

Comment: @eponini updated post with some code

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like This:

```js
function click_button(_id){
  document.getElementById(_id).click();
}

click_button('btn');
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="ClickMe" onclick="alert('Welcome');"/>
```